# GNS3 ASA not pinging itself

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, gns3

I have been playing with network stuff so I installed `GNS3` network simulator.

I have deployed `ASA 8.4` image and it has loaded fine.

I connected it with basic `Switch`

`switch`-----`ASA`

I have configured IP address on an interface and executed `no shut`. I then tried to ping itself but ping did not work :(

I have restart GNS3 also but didn't work :(

```
interface GigabitEthernet0
 no nameif
 no security-level
 ip address 192.168.56.2 255.255.255.0
!
```

Trying to ping itself

```
fw01# ping 192.168.56.2
Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 192.168.56.2, timeout is 2 seconds:
No route to host 192.168.56.2

Success rate is 0 percent (0/1)
fw01#
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the interface name otherwise the interface will remain unreachable.

e.g.

```
interface gi0
 nameif inside
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 no shutdown
```

To verify your interface status

```
show int ip brief
```

Comment: You also need a security level configured. Although most code versions will automatically set a security level of `0` for you once you set the name. Except if you set the name `inside`, in which case it sets a security level of `100`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you also have a set a security level for the interfaces in an ASA. From what I remember, there's three things that need to be configured for each interface:
Name
Security Level
IP Address

Comment: Hi MMusgrove, welcome to NESE. You posted the correct answer, however, would you be willing to elaborate and/or provide syntax or configuration examples to help the original poster and future readers?